# Is it possible to query in graphql with null value UUID when @include false or @skip true

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

For Apollo GraphQL:

I'm trying to query on a field where it requires a UUID. But I don't need the field if the variable is null. I was wondering what's the best way to handle this? I'm currently passing a default documentId to work around this.

This is an example of the query

```
query GetOverview($initialFetch: Boolean!, $documentId: UUID!) {
  organization {
  name
  inode(id: $documentId) @include(if: $initialFetch) {
    ... on Inode {
      inodeId
      parent {
        inodeId
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Variable: 
`{ initialFetch: true, documentId: ... }`

This is the error I get back

`"Variable "$documentId" of required type "UUID!" was not provided."`

Comment: You probably get this specific error because `$documentId` is defined as not null-able. Try `$documentId: UUID`. You probably need to check `initialFetch` and `documentId` are valid before calling the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about that Apollo **skip** was what I needed which would skip the HoC altogether. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-skip

Its also probably recommended to split the queries especially in cases like this. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/query-splitting.html

Sudo code of the correct approach:

```
query GetOrgName {
  organization {
    name
  }
}

query GetInode {
  inode(id: $documentId) {
    ... on Inode {
      inodeId
      parent {
        inodeId
      }
    }
  }
}

const splitQuery = compose(
  graphql(getOrgName, { name: "orgName" }), 
  graphql(getInode, { 
    name: "inode", 
    skip: props => !props.initialFetch
  })
)(Component);
```